# The named parameter 'children' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Anyone can find the error of this segment? I'm trying to view some data sets but this error keeps coming.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow, it is recommended you post the actual code rather than a screenshot as it is easier to read and edit. Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Container` widget does not have any `children` property. You need to change it with the `child`.

Comment: Restart your IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike a Row or Column or Stack which are multi-child layout widgets, Container is a single child layout widget. So you cannot use a list of widgets as children of the container.

Please refer Flutter docs layout widgets : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout to understand different types of Single-child layout widgets and Multi-child layout widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Container does not have the `children` property just change it to `child`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it in two ways:

1. Keeping the container and change the children to the child.
2. changing the container to the Column or Row.